# Datepicker javascript disable option if day == 6

Tags: javascript, datepicker

please help, how to disable option:

```
<option value="17-19">17-19</option>
<option value="19-22">19-22</option>
```

If user choose Saturday i use datepicker

```
<select placeholder="hour">
        <option selected disabled value="">select hour</option>
        <option value="7-9">7-9</option>
        <option value="9-11">9-11</option>
        <option value="11-13">11-13</option>
        <option value="13-15">13-15</option>
        <option value="15-17">15-17</option>
        <option value="17-19">17-19</option>
        <option value="19-22">19-22</option>
    </select>

<input id="datepicker" class="datepiker" autocomplete="off" type="text"  min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" placeholder="select date" required></div>
```

Comment: if user check saturday option value 19-22 disable

Answer (score 0):

If u want to do it by yourself, you can use [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) on your input element and check if date day === 6 with [GetDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) when input changes. You can disable options by changing their 'disabled' property.

You can check how I did this bellow.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const options = document.querySelectorAll('option');
const input = document.querySelector('#datepicker');

const toggleOptions = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
  const date = new Date(e.target.value)
  if(date.getDay() === 6) {
    select.value = "";
    options[6].disabled = true;
    options[7].disabled = true;
  } else {
    options[6].disabled = false;
    options[7].disabled = false;
  }
}

input.addEventListener('change', toggleOptions )
```

```html
<select placeholder="hour">
        <option selected disabled value="">select hour</option>
        <option value="7-9">7-9</option>
        <option value="9-11">9-11</option>
        <option value="11-13">11-13</option>
        <option value="13-15">13-15</option>
        <option value="15-17">15-17</option>
        <option value="17-19">17-19</option>
        <option value="19-22">19-22</option>
    </select>

<input id="datepicker" class="datepiker" autocomplete="off" type="text"  placeholder="select date" required>
```